# SQLAlchemy relationships across multiple tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a relationship that spans across 3 tables but I can't quite figure out the syntax.

I have 3 tables `TableA`, `TableB` and `TableC` and the relationship I'm trying to model is:

```
TableA.my_relationship = relationship(
    'TableC',
    primaryjoin='and_(TableA.fk == TableB.pk, TableB.fk == TableC.pk)',
    viewonly=True
)
```

so that on an instance of `TableA` I can do `instance_of_a.my_relationship` to get the `TableC` record that's indirectly associated with `instance_of_a`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```py
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('b.id'))

    # method one - put everything into primaryjoin.
    # will work for simple lazy loads but for eager loads the ORM
    # will fail to build up the FROM to correctly include B
    cs = relationship("C",
                # C.id is "foreign" because there can be many C.ids for one A.id
                # B.id is "remote", it sort of means "this is where the stuff
                # starts that's not directly part of the A side"
                primaryjoin="and_(A.b_id == remote(B.id), foreign(C.id) == B.c_id)",
                viewonly=True)

    # method two - split out the middle table into "secondary".
    # note 'b' is the table name in metadata.
    # this method will work better, as the ORM can also handle 
    # eager loading with this one.
    c_via_secondary = relationship("C", secondary="b",
                        primaryjoin="A.b_id == B.id", secondaryjoin="C.id == B.c_id",
                        viewonly=True)
class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    c_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('c.id'))

class C(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'c'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

e = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(e)

sess = Session(e)

sess.add(C(id=1))
sess.flush()
sess.add(B(id=1, c_id=1))
sess.flush()
sess.add(A(b_id=1))
sess.flush()

a1 = sess.query(A).first()
print(a1.cs)

print(a1.c_via_secondary)
```

Comment: Is one relationship defining method preferred over the other for any reason? The explicit referencing of `secondary` in method two intuitively seems cleaner than the complex `primaryjoin` str in method one... but method one seems like it could be more powerful.

Comment: this is kind of a weird one, so as far as secondary, that isn't how "secondary" was intended to be used originally, e.g. it expects the FKs to be all in the middle.  I'm not sure if that "Secondary" relationship will actually manage to persist correctly, e.g. it might need to be viewonly=True also.   The ORM will also make different choices when building out things like eager loads, and in that regard the "secondary" version may make better decisions since it knows that there is an extra table in the FROM clause.

Comment: confirmed, joined eager loading only works with the second one, the first one fails to build up the FROM correctly

Comment: and what if 'b' table is not mapped to class and is just a secondary table?
How the 'secondary' method joins would changed?