# SQLAlchemy : how to filter based on a deeply related hybrid attribute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have three models:

### A => B => C

with one-to-many relationships.

- A has a foreign key to B, named b
- B has a foreign key to C, named c

### My goal:

On my A class, I would like to be able to have a shortcut attribute directly to C

On the instance level, it's easy:

```
@hybrid_property
def shortcut_c(self):
    return self.b.c
```

However, I can't figure out how to enable queries like this:

```
session.query(A).filter(A.shortcut_c.has(some_c_column=1)).all()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLAlchemy relationships across multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580649/sqlalchemy-relationships-across-multiple-tables)